# How to input the dictionary structure in 'values' argument using the aws_ssm_parameter in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I have one parameter in AWS System Manager, type of the value is string, but value has a dictionary structure:

Value:

{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2","key3": "value3"}

Now i'm trying to create this parameter using the Terraform. But i received an error, when trying to write this in *aws_ssm_parameter resource*:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "Paramet" {
  name = "/dev/parameter/new"
  description = "Sample config values"
  type = "String"
  value = "{key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3}"
}
```

Error:

> $ terraform plan
>
> Error: Missing newline after argument
>
> on main.tf line 90, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "Paramet":   90:
>   value = "{key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3}"
>
> An argument definition must end with a newline.

This error is connected with  syntax, but i can't understand, how to fix this correctly.

Please advice, how to input correctly this value in aws_ssm_parameter resource?

Comment: The error appears due to the ```"``` that are not escaped. To escape them you could add a backslash ```\``` in front of each ```"```. That being said, using heredoc as suggested in @tedsmitt' s answer is certainly more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) syntax to achieve this. The below should work for you

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "Parameter" {
  name = "/dev/parameter/new"
  description = "Sample config values"
  type = "String"
  value = <<EOF
  {
      "key1" : "value1", 
      "key2" : "value2", 
      "key3" : "value3"
  }
  EOF
}
```

Comment: Often times you would want to use ```<<-``` instead of just ```<<```. The difference is, that the former automatically removes the indentation automatically according to the indentation of the closing ```EOF```.